# AI Prolog exercise

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

Here is the Question following:

For this question we consider binary expression-trees whose leaves are either of the form `tree(empty, Num, empty)` where Num is a number, or `tree(empty, z, empty)` in which case we will think of the letter z as a kind of "variable".

Every tree is either a leaf or of the form `tree(L, Op, R)` where L and R are the left and right subtrees, and Op is one of the arithmetic operators '+', '-', '*', '/' (signifying addition, subtraction, multiplication and division).

Write a predicate `tree_eval(Value, Tree, Eval)` that binds Eval to the result of evaluating the expression-tree Tree, with the variable z set equal to the specified Value. For example:

```
?- tree_eval(2, tree(tree(empty,z,empty),
             '+',tree(tree(empty,1,empty),
                  '/',tree(empty,z,empty))), Eval).
Eval = 2.5 ;
false.

?- tree_eval(5, tree(tree(empty,z,empty),
             '+',tree(tree(empty,1,empty),
                  '/',tree(empty,z,empty))), Eval).
Eval = 5.2 ;
false.
```

Some good ideas?

Could we achieve it without using cut(!)?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

It is a shame you wouldn't even try to solve it before asking for help.

Your question almost directly translates to a solution. When there is a Num in the middle of the tree:

```
tree_eval(_Value, tree(empty,Num,empty), Num).
```

When there is a variable:

```
tree_eval(Value, tree(empty,z,empty), Value).
```

And the general case:

```
tree_eval(Value, tree(tree(LL,LOp,LR),Op,tree(RL,ROp,RR)), Eval) :-
    tree_eval(Value, tree(LL,LOp,LR), LEval),
    tree_eval(Value, tree(RL,ROp,RR), REval),
    Expr =.. [Op,LEval,REval], % is there an easier way to do this?
    Eval is Expr.
```

Now as you notice, this solution has no cuts. They are not necessary, because at a time, only one of the three clauses can be true. For one of the clauses, however, I couldn't come up with a way to make the head unambiguous. [This](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.6%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/typetest.html%27%29%29) might be of help.